# Stop video poster stretch in react-player (which uses HTML vide)?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, video, react-player

I don't want the poster image to occupy the full dimensions of this video but maintain aspect ratio and get centred. How can I achieve that?
Note: This is a snippet. The actual code is reactjs code sing react player for embedding the video. I will be using the config.file.attributes for sending the required attrs to  s seen [here](https://github.com/cookpete/react-player/issues/301). using `style="object-fit=none"` works but is that possible for react player?

code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The video poster attribute</h1>

<video width="900" height="1240" poster="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" controls object-fit="none">
   <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If that's an option for you, you can always create a wrapper `<div>` around your video with the dimensions you want to use. Make that div have `position: relative`. Then, you say that the video has `position: absolute` and `width: 100%` (means it occupies 100% of its parent's available space). Height will adapt automatically and video's aspect ratio will be respected. And to center the video you can use, for example, `display: flex; align-items: center;` on the wrapper div. Hope it works!